# su command not set BASH_VERSION value and not load profile

Tags: ssh, bash, bashrc

I have a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server version and have a strange problem creating a new user and use it in the shell from a ssh connection. The steps to reproduce it:

1. Use he root account to create new user using `useradd --create-home test`.
2. Login from root user to test using `su test`.

The result:

```bash
root@server:~# useradd --create-home test;
root@server:~# echo $BASH_VERSION
5.0.17(1)-release
root@server:~# su test;
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
$
```

The prompt is not set, the environment variables are not loaded, the autocomplete is not working, the aliases are not working, it is as if the .profile and .bashrc file do not exist but they do exist and have their permissions set correctly:

```bash
root@server:/home/test# md5sum /etc/skel/.profile ./.profile 
f4e81ade7d6f9fb342541152d08e7a97  /etc/skel/.profile
f4e81ade7d6f9fb342541152d08e7a97  ./.profile
root@server:/home/test# md5sum /etc/skel/.bashrc ./.bashrc
1f98b8f3f3c8f8927eca945d59dcc1c6  /etc/skel/.bashrc
1f98b8f3f3c8f8927eca945d59dcc1c6  ./.bashrc
root@server:/home/test# ls -lah
total 24K
drwxr-xr-x  3 test test 4.0K Sep 18 13:18 .
drwxr-xr-x  9 root root 4.0K Sep 18 13:17 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 test test  220 Feb 25  2020 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--  1 test test 3.7K Feb 25  2020 .bashrc
-rw-r--r--  1 test test  807 Feb 25  2020 .profile
```

Why does the profile not load when I log in as a test user?

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation of `su` says:

> For backward compatibility, `su` defaults to not change the current directory and to only set the environment variables HOME and SHELL (plus USER and LOGNAME if the target user is not root). It is recommended to always use the `--login` option (instead of its shortcut `-`) to avoid side effects caused by mixing environments.

When under the `--login` or `-l`, `su` also runs a *login* shell, which in turn sources the `.profile` (`.bashrc` should be sourced always).

To see which files are loaded, insert a simple line towards the beginning of them:

```
echo "$BASH_SOURCE" >&2
```

Comment: Thanks, but when `su -l test` have same result.

Comment: What shell does the user run? Probably not bash, right?

Comment: The root user `$0` is `-bash` and `test` user says `sh`. In the `/etc/passwd` the root user use `/bin/bash` and the test user use `/bin/sh`. Don't gnu/linux based systems create users based on the main system shell by default?

Comment: Read the documentation of `useradd`. The version I have installed says *...  the default login shell specified by the SHELL variable in `/etc/default/useradd`*